# Problem multiplying rows starting by the same string in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
hhn2_df
Out[58]: 
         No_Households
NUTS_ID               
AT11          544529.0
AT12          754676.0
BE22          339414.0
BE23          615307.0
BE24          448142.0
               ...
SE22          590922.0
SE23          797748.0
SE31          371051.0
SE32          162199.0
SE33          217290.0

[231 rows x 1 columns]
```

And:

```
nuts2dkmean
Out[59]: 
         Percentage_Population
NUTS_ID                       
AT111                 0.129403
AT112                 0.536150
AT113                 0.334447
AT121                 0.147773
AT122                 0.155859
                       ...
SK023                 0.372212
SK031                 0.514279
SK032                 0.485721
SK041                 0.507516
SK042                 0.492484

[1166 rows x 1 columns]
```

I'm trying to multiply all the elements starting by the four same characters in the two dataframes.
As an example, in the second dataframe AT111 and AT112 would be multiplied by AT11 in the first dataframe, SK031 and SK032 (from the second dataframe) would be multiplied by SK03 (from the first dataframe) and so on. The elements are not in the same order in the two dataframes and I don't know if that constitutes a problem.

I tried doing:

```
new_df = nuts2dkmean.rename(index=lambda x: x[:4]).mul(hhn2_df).set_index(nuts2dkmean.index)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Desktop\Eurostat Datasets\untitled12.py", line 74, in <module>
    new_df = nuts2dkmean.rename(index=lambda x: x[:4]).mul(hhn2_df).set_index(nuts2dkmean.index)

  File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4594, in set_index
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 1213 rows, received array of length 1166
```

I'd appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reindex`:

```
 df2['Percentage_Population'] * df1.reindex(df2.index.str[:4])['No_Households'].values
```